# Assembly - why is %rsp decremented by so much, and why are arguments stored at the top of the stack?

Tags: c, assembly

Assembly newbie here... I wrote the following simple C program:

```
void fun(int x, int* y)
{
  char arr[4];
  int* sp;
  sp = y;
}

int main()
{
  int i = 4;
  fun(i, &i);
  return 0;
}
```

I compiled it with gcc and ran objdump with -S, but the Assembly code output is confusing me:

```
000000000040055d <fun>:
void fun(int x, int* y)
{
  40055d:       55                      push   %rbp
  40055e:       48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
  400561:       48 83 ec 30             sub    $0x30,%rsp
  400565:       89 7d dc                mov    %edi,-0x24(%rbp)
  400568:       48 89 75 d0             mov    %rsi,-0x30(%rbp)
  40056c:       64 48 8b 04 25 28 00    mov    %fs:0x28,%rax
  400573:       00 00
  400575:       48 89 45 f8             mov    %rax,-0x8(%rbp)
  400579:       31 c0                   xor    %eax,%eax
  char arr[4];
  int* sp;
  sp = y;
  40057b:       48 8b 45 d0             mov    -0x30(%rbp),%rax
  40057f:       48 89 45 e8             mov    %rax,-0x18(%rbp)
}
  400583:       48 8b 45 f8             mov    -0x8(%rbp),%rax
  400587:       64 48 33 04 25 28 00    xor    %fs:0x28,%rax
  40058e:       00 00
  400590:       74 05                   je     400597 <fun+0x3a>
  400592:       e8 a9 fe ff ff          callq  400440 <__stack_chk_fail@plt>
  400597:       c9                      leaveq
  400598:       c3                      retq

0000000000400599 <main>:

int main()
{
  400599:       55                      push   %rbp
  40059a:       48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
  40059d:       48 83 ec 10             sub    $0x10,%rsp
  int i = 4;
  4005a1:       c7 45 fc 04 00 00 00    movl   $0x4,-0x4(%rbp)
  fun(i, &i);
  4005a8:       8b 45 fc                mov    -0x4(%rbp),%eax
  4005ab:       48 8d 55 fc             lea    -0x4(%rbp),%rdx
  4005af:       48 89 d6                mov    %rdx,%rsi
  4005b2:       89 c7                   mov    %eax,%edi
  4005b4:       e8 a4 ff ff ff          callq  40055d <fun>
  return 0;
  4005b9:       b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
}
  4005be:       c9                      leaveq
  4005bf:       c3                      retq
```

First, in the line:

```
  400561:       48 83 ec 30             sub    $0x30,%rsp
```

Why is the stack pointer decremented so much in the call to 'fun' (48 bytes)? I assume it has to do with alignment issues, but I cannot visualize why it would need so much space (I only count 12 bytes for local variables (assuming 8 byte pointers))?

Second, I thought that in x86_64, the arguments to a function are either stored in specific registers, or if there are a lot of them, just 'above' (with a downward growing stack) the base pointer, %rbp. Like in the picture at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack#Structure  except 'upside-down'.

But the lines:

```
  400565:       89 7d dc                mov    %edi,-0x24(%rbp)
  400568:       48 89 75 d0             mov    %rsi,-0x30(%rbp)
```

suggest to me that they are being stored way down from the base of the stack (%rsi and %edi are where main put the arguments, right before calling 'fun', and 0x30 down from %rbp is exactly where the stack pointer is pointing...). And when I try to do stuff with them , like assigning their values to local variables, it grabs them from those locations near the head of the stack:

```
  sp = y;
  40057b:       48 8b 45 d0             mov    -0x30(%rbp),%rax
  40057f:       48 89 45 e8             mov    %rax,-0x18(%rbp)
```

... what is going on here?! I would expect them to grab the arguments from either the registers they were stored in, or just above the base pointer, where I thought they are 'supposed to be', according to every basic tutorial I read. Every answer and post I found on here related to stack frame questions confirms my understanding of what stack frames "should" look like, so why is my Assembly output so darn weird?

Comment: rather than doing objdump you can get your compiler to output the asm that it generated... generally with gcc or clang: `gcc file.c -S -o file.s` (or similar)

Comment: Is it shadow space for the callee to spill registers?

Comment: Looking at un-optimized code isn't very useful.  It looks sloppy because, well, you said it didn't matter.  Seeing 32-bit Windows style exception handling in 64-bit code with AT&T syntax is bound to cause some raised eyebrows, gladiator-vs-dinosaur movie style ;)  You have to be a bit more explicit about your tooling.

Comment: You forgot to turn optimization on, so you get inefficient code out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you're compiling without optimization, the compiler does lots of extra stuff to maybe make things easier to debug, which use lots of extra space.

- it does not attempt to compress the stack frame to reuse memory for anything, or get rid of any unused things.
- it redundantly copies the arguments into the stack frame (which requires still more memory)
- it copies a 'canary' on to the stack to guard against stack smashing buffer overflows (even though they can't happen in this code).

Try turning on optimization, and you'll see more real code.

Answer (score 4):

Because that stuff is a hideously simplified version of what really goes on. It's like wondering why Newtonian mechanics doesn't model the movement of the planets down to the millimeter. Compilers need stack space for all sorts of things. For example, saving callee-saved registers.

Also, the fundamental fact is that debug-mode compilations contain all sorts of debugging and checking machinery. The compiler outputs all sorts of code that checks that your code is correct, for example the call to `__stack_chk_fail`.

There are only two ways to understand the output of a given compiler. The first is to implement the compiler, or be otherwise very familiar with the implementation. The second is to accept that whatever you understand is a gross simplification. Pick one.

Answer (score 0):

This is 64 bit code. 0x30 of stack space corresponds to 6 slots on the stack. You have what appears to be:

- 2 slots for function arguments (which happen also to be passed in registers)
- 2 slots for local variables
- 1 slot for saving the AX register
- 1 slot looks like a stack guard, probably related to DEBUG mode.

Best thing is to experiment rather than ask questions. Try compiling in different modes (DEBUG, optimisation, etc), and with different numbers and types of arguments and variables. Sometimes asking other people is just too easy -- you learn better by doing your own experiments.